# How do I make a DOM object follow a circular path with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, physics

I'm trying to make a DOM object follow a circular path with jQuery.

So far, I'm trying to find the path by re-arranging a simple formula to determine a circle, so in pseudocode:

x = whatever.
y = abs(sqrt(constant) -x)

This is what I have so far:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() 
{
    //get intitial ratio
    vRatio = (sky.dHeight - sky.height ) / (sky.height - 100)
    hRatio = (sky.dHeight - sky.height ) / (sky.width - 100)

    rawX = $(window).scrollTop() / hRatio;
    x = rawX - sky.width/2;
    y = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(sky.width/2) - x);

    console.log(x)
    console.log(y)

    sun.ob.css({left : rawX, top: y})
})
```

Currently, it's following a triangular path rather than the gentle circular flow I was seeking with my eyes.

Just to give some context, this is on a parallax style document where the height is 000's of px tall (hence the ratios).

Comment: a jfiddle would be handy here+ when i need something rotated in a circle i usually use the cos() and sin() functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made this fiddle for you - uses some CSS rotation while scrolling down:

http://jsfiddle.net/cWqKL/3/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight);
    var r = 180 * scrollPercent;
    TweenMax.to($('#orbit'), 0.5, {
        rotation: r
    });
});
```

Should work on any window size.

Comment: Wonderful answer! But because of browser support, I have to keep away from CSS3 attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a circular path then you probably want to use cos and sin ;)

I've made a quick example of a sun that is rotating within a div called "sky":
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jorisvanleeuwen/jYLM7/)

```
var progression = 0;
update();
function update(){

    var radiusX = 200;
    var radiusY = 100;
    var speed = 0.01;

    var sky = $("#sky");
    var sun = $("#sun");

    var skyCenterX = sky.width() * 0.5 - sun.width() * 0.5;
    var skyCenterY = sky.height() * 0.5 - sun.height() * 0.5;

    progression = progression + speed;

    var sunX = skyCenterX + radiusX * Math.cos(progression);
    var sunY = skyCenterY + radiusY * Math.sin(progression);

    $("#sun").css({left : sunX, top: sunY});

    setTimeout(function(){update();}, 10);
}
```

I hope this is helpfull :D

Comment: Almost! As It is tied to the scrollTop position, I annoyingly want my sun to only complete half a rotation. I have tried modifying this code, and plugging in different values for the progression based on scrollTop, but my sun still goes 'below the horizon' (the bottom of the screen).

Answer (score 2):

Generally for `(x,y)` pairs of a circle you need to use `sin` and `cos`, so something like

```
x = x0 + radius*Math.cos(angle)
y = y0 + radius*Math.sin(angle)
```

for a circle centered at `(x0,y0)`, with a given `radius`.

It looks like you might want to start with a value of `x` and then determine `y`?  For that you could use:

```
angle = Math.acos( (x-x0)/radius )
y = y0 + radius*Math.sin(angle)
```